# If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $f(x)f(x+2)+f(x+1)=0$ for all $x$, prove $f(x)=0$ for infinitely many $x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)f(x+2)+f(x+1)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that there are infinitely many real values of $x$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Here is my approach (by inspection):

For $x=0$ we have $f(0)f(2)+f(1)=0$ (Eq1).

Now, if $f(0)=0$, then $f(1)=0$. From $f(1)f(3)+f(2)=0$ for $x=1$ we can also conclude that $f(2)=0$. In this case it's not hard to prove that $f(n)=0\ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

On the other hand, if $f(0)>0$, then Eq1 let us conclude that $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ have opposite signs, say $f(1)<0<f(2)$. In this case, the IVT guarantes that there exists a $c\in (1,2)$ such that $f(c)=0$. Again, it's not hard to prove that $f(n+c)=0\ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I am stuck with the case where $f(0)<0$. In this case $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ have the same sign and I couldn't figure out what to do next. Any hint to this case or a different approach would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(x)=-1$ satisfies the conditions but has no zeros.

Comment: Ohh. I was tricked by my professor then. It would be a interesting problem if we add $f(x)\geqslant 0$ dough. This problem got me thinking for days. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to exclude the counterexample offered by @dxiv, you need to add the condition that there exists _at least one_ $x_0\in\mathbb R$ with $f(x_0)=0$. But then you can actually drop the continuity requirement.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)f(x+2)+f(x+1)=0
$

Suppose there are
only finitely many $x$
such that
$f(x)=0$.
Then there is a largest such $x$.
Call it $x_0$.

Then
$f(x_0)=0$ and,
for all $x > x_0$
$f(x) \ne 0$.
Since $f$ is continuous,
$f(x)$ is of constant sign
for all $x > x_0$.

Assume $f(x)>0$ for
$x > x_0$.
This works just as well for
$f(x) < 0$.

We have
$0
=f(x_0)f(x_0+2)+f(x_0+1)
$.
Since $f(x_0)=0$,
$f(x_0+1)=0$
which contradicts the
definition of $x_0$.

Therefore there is no largest $x$ such that
$f(x)=0$.

(added later)

In particular,
this shows that if
$f(x)=0$
then $f(x+1)=0$
so
$f(x+n)=0$
for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: You don’t even need continuity. But you do need to assume the existence of at least one root.